# Angularjs in development: using a service on another port

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, gruntjs

I'm developing an angularjs client for consuming a RESTful service I wrote in Django. I'm not currently doing any development on the service and don't need to be able to change it conveniently.

I do want to change the angular client conveniently. When I'm developing I want to leave the service running either through a dockerized Nginx server on `127.0.0.1` or on the Django development server on `127.0.0.1:8000`, either is fine. By default grunt serves the angular application on `127.0.0.1:9000`, meaning calls to my service such as (coffeescript):

```
return $resource('api/logos/:id')
```

are looking for `127.0.0.1:9000/api/…`, where it won't be found. How do I either strip or change the port number that angular is looking for its services on while developing?

EDIT: `Gruntfile` as requested:

```
// Generated on 2015-03-05 using generator-angular 0.11.1
'use strict';

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {

// Load grunt tasks automatically
require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

// Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
require('time-grunt')(grunt);

// Configurable paths for the application
var appConfig = {
    app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
    dist: 'dist'
};

// Define the configuration for all the tasks
grunt.initConfig({

    // Project settings
    yeoman: appConfig,

    // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
    watch: {
    bower: {
        files: ['bower.json'],
        tasks: ['wiredep']
    },
    coffee: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.{coffee,litcoffee,coffee.md}'],
        tasks: ['newer:coffee:dist']
    },
    coffeeTest: {
        files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.{coffee,litcoffee,coffee.md}'],
        tasks: ['newer:coffee:test', 'karma']
    },
    compass: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
        tasks: ['compass:server', 'autoprefixer']
    },
    gruntfile: {
        files: ['Gruntfile.js']
    },
    livereload: {
        options: {
        livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
        },
        files: [
        '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
        '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
        '.tmp/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
        '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
        ]
    }
    },

    // The actual grunt server settings
    connect: {
    options: {
        port: 9000,
        // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
        hostname: '0.0.0.0',
        livereload: 35729
    },
    livereload: {
        options: {
        open: false,
        middleware: function (connect) {
            return [
            connect.static('.tmp'),
            connect().use(
                '/bower_components',
                connect.static('./bower_components')
            ),
            connect().use(
                '/app/styles',
                connect.static('./app/styles')
            ),
            connect.static(appConfig.app)
            ];
        }
        }
    },
    test: {
        options: {
        port: 9001,
        middleware: function (connect) {
            return [
            connect.static('.tmp'),
            connect.static('test'),
            connect().use(
                '/bower_components',
                connect.static('./bower_components')
            ),
            connect.static(appConfig.app)
            ];
        }
        }
    },
    dist: {
        options: {
        open: true,
        base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }
    }
    },

    // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
    jshint: {
    options: {
        jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
        reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
    },
    all: {
        src: [
        'Gruntfile.js'
        ]
    }
    },

    // Empties folders to start fresh
    clean: {
    dist: {
        files: [{
        dot: true,
        src: [
            '.tmp',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*',
            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git{,*/}*'
        ]
        }]
    },
    server: '.tmp'
    },

    // Add vendor prefixed styles
    autoprefixer: {
    options: {
        browsers: ['last 1 version']
    },
    server: {
        options: {
        map: true,
        },
        files: [{
        expand: true,
        cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
        src: '{,*/}*.css',
        dest: '.tmp/styles/'
        }]
    },
    dist: {
        files: [{
        expand: true,
        cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
        src: '{,*/}*.css',
        dest: '.tmp/styles/'
        }]
    }
    },

    // Automatically inject Bower components into the app
    wiredep: {
    app: {
        src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
        ignorePath:  /\.\.\//
    },
    test: {
        devDependencies: true,
        src: '<%= karma.unit.configFile %>',
        ignorePath:  /\.\.\//,
        fileTypes:{
        coffee: {
            block: /(([\s\t]*)#\s*?bower:\s*?(\S*))(\n|\r|.)*?(#\s*endbower)/gi,
            detect: {
                js: /'(.*\.js)'/gi,
                coffee: /'(.*\.coffee)'/gi
            },
            replace: {
            js: '\'{{filePath}}\'',
            coffee: '\'{{filePath}}\''
            }
        }
        }
    },
    sass: {
        src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
        ignorePath: /(\.\.\/){1,2}bower_components\//
    }
    },

    // Compiles CoffeeScript to JavaScript
    coffee: {
    options: {
        sourceMap: true,
        sourceRoot: ''
    },
    dist: {
        files: [{
        expand: true,
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
        src: '{,*/}*.coffee',
        dest: '.tmp/scripts',
        ext: '.js'
        }]
    },
    test: {
        files: [{
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'test/spec',
        src: '{,*/}*.coffee',
        dest: '.tmp/spec',
        ext: '.js'
        }]
    }
    },

    // Compiles Sass to CSS and generates necessary files if requested
    compass: {
    options: {
        sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
        cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
        generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
        imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
        javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
        fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
        importPath: './bower_components',
        httpImagesPath: '/images',
        httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
        httpFontsPath: '/styles/fonts',
        relativeAssets: false,
        assetCacheBuster: false,
        raw: 'Sass::Script::Number.precision = 10\n'
    },
    dist: {
        options: {
        generatedImagesDir: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/generated'
        }
    },
    server: {
        options: {
        sourcemap: true
        }
    }
    },

    // Renames files for browser caching purposes
    filerev: {
    dist: {
        src: [
        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
        ]
    }
    },

    // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
    // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
    // additional tasks can operate on them
    useminPrepare: {
    html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
    options: {
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
        flow: {
        html: {
            steps: {
            js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
            css: ['cssmin']
            },
            post: {}
        }
        }
    }
    },

    // Performs rewrites based on filerev and the useminPrepare configuration
    usemin: {
    html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
    css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
    options: {
        assetsDirs: [
        '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles'
        ]
    }
    },

    // The following *-min tasks will produce minified files in the dist folder
    // By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care of
    // minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not wish
    // to use the Usemin blocks.
    // cssmin: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
    //         '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // uglify: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
    //         '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // concat: {
    //   dist: {}
    // },

    imagemin: {
    dist: {
        files: [{
        expand: true,
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
        src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }]
    }
    },

    svgmin: {
    dist: {
        files: [{
        expand: true,
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
        src: '{,*/}*.svg',
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }]
    }
    },

    htmlmin: {
    dist: {
        options: {
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        conservativeCollapse: true,
        collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
        removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
        removeOptionalTags: true
        },
        files: [{
        expand: true,
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
        src: ['*.html', 'views/{,*/}*.html'],
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }]
    }
    },

    // ng-annotate tries to make the code safe for minification automatically
    // by using the Angular long form for dependency injection.
    ngAnnotate: {
    dist: {
        files: [{
        expand: true,
        cwd: '.tmp/concat/scripts',
        src: '*.js',
        dest: '.tmp/concat/scripts'
        }]
    }
    },

    // Replace Google CDN references
    cdnify: {
    dist: {
        html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/*.html']
    }
    },

    // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
    copy: {
    dist: {
        files: [{
        expand: true,
        dot: true,
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
        src: [
            '*.{ico,png,txt}',
            '.htaccess',
            '*.html',
            'views/{,*/}*.html',
            'images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
            'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*'
        ]
        }, {
        expand: true,
        cwd: '.tmp/images',
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
        src: ['generated/*']
        }, {
        expand: true,
        cwd: '.',
        src: 'bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/fonts/bootstrap/*',
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }]
    },
    styles: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
        dest: '.tmp/styles/',
        src: '{,*/}*.css'
    }
    },

    // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up the build process
    concurrent: {
    server: [
        'coffee:dist',
        'compass:server'
    ],
    test: [
        'coffee',
        'compass'
    ],
    dist: [
        'coffee',
        'compass:dist',
        'imagemin',
        'svgmin'
    ]
    },

    // Test settings
    karma: {
    unit: {
        configFile: 'test/karma.conf.coffee',
        singleRun: true
    }
    }
});


grunt.registerTask('serve', 'Compile then start a connect web server', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
    return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
    'clean:server',
    'wiredep',
    'concurrent:server',
    'autoprefixer:server',
    'connect:livereload',
    'watch'
    ]);
});

grunt.registerTask('server', 'DEPRECATED TASK. Use the "serve" task instead', function (target) {
    grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
    grunt.task.run(['serve:' + target]);
});

grunt.registerTask('test', [
    'clean:server',
    'wiredep',
    'concurrent:test',
    'autoprefixer',
    'connect:test',
    'karma'
]);

grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'wiredep',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    'concat',
    'ngAnnotate',
    'copy:dist',
    'cdnify',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'filerev',
    'usemin',
    'htmlmin'
]);

grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'newer:jshint',
    'test',
    'build'
]);
};
```

Comment: Which Grunt plugin are you using to serve the files? Including the relevant configuration (Gruntfile) in the question may be helpful too.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos I'm using the standard configuration from the yeoman angular generator, with the exception that I've changed the host to 0.0.0.0 because grunt is also working in a docker container. I've edited the questions to include the Gruntfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler way to do this is to enable [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) on the service. Since your service is using Django you should be able to use the  [Django CORS headers app](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers).

Install it with pip, then add `corsheaders` to your installed apps. Next, add the CORS middleware *before* Django's common middleware in your settings like so:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
)
```

Finally, whitelist the port your angular application is on, again in your Django settings, like so:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'localhost:9000' # for example. Your port may vary.
)
```

On the angular side you'll need to give a full path to your services while in development otherwise the port difference will cause a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue, this is how I addressed it:

1. An interceptor modifies the URL of the API calls:

   ```
   angular.module(...).config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
       $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['env', function(env) {
           return {
               'request': function(config) {
                   if( config.url.indexOf('/api/') === 0 ) {
                       config.url = env.apiContextPath + config.url;
                   }
                   return config;
               }
           };
       }]);
   }]);
   ```

   You may need to tweak the `indexOf(...)` part, but you get the general idea. Read [here](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors) about interceptors.
2. The `env` service holds the application *environment* configuration, i.e. it is different for local development, dev server, production etc. I am generating it in Grunt with [grunt-ng-constant](https://github.com/werk85/grunt-ng-constant), there are lots of ways to do it - not getting into details here.
3. Finally you have to setup `grunt-connect` to use proxies. DISCLAIMER: My configuration is slightly different than this, so while the general idea is probably correct, some details may need tweaking!

   You need [grunt-connect-proxy](https://github.com/drewzboto/grunt-connect-proxy). Just follow the steps in their documentation, in short:

   - Add proxy configuration to `connect:livereload`
   - Add the proxy middleware to your middlewares (I believe preferably first)

     ```
     livereload: {
         options: {
             open: false,
             middleware: function (connect) {
                 return [
                     // ADDED PROXY MIDDLEWARE HERE
                     require('grunt-connect-proxy/lib/utils').proxyRequest,
                     connect.static('.tmp'),
                     connect().use(
                         '/bower_components',
                         connect.static('./bower_components')
                     ),
                     connect().use(
                         '/app/styles',
                         connect.static('./app/styles')
                     ),
                     connect.static(appConfig.app)
                 ];
             }
         },
         proxies: [{
             context: '/api',
             host: 'localhost', // the host serving your API
             port: 8000         // again the port of your API server
         }]
     },
     ```
   - Add the configureProxy task to the server task:

     ```
     grunt.registerTask('serve', 'Compile then start a connect web server', function (target) {
         if (target === 'dist') {
             return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
         }

         grunt.task.run([
             'clean:server',
             'wiredep',
             'concurrent:server',
             'autoprefixer:server',
             'configureProxies:livereload',  // HERE
             'connect:livereload',
             'watch'
         ]);
     });
     ```

Comment: This looks like what I need. I'm away from my system now so it'll be a while before I can try it out but I'll accept once I've got things working, editing as necessary.